# Vectorize a numpy discount calculation

Tags: python, numpy, recursion

A common term in finance and reinforcement learning is the discounted cumulative reward `C[i]` based on a time series of raw rewards `R[i]`. Given an array `R`, we'd like to calculate `C[i]` satisfying the recurrence `C[i] = R[i] + discount * C[i+1]` with `C[-1] = R[-1]` (and return the full array `C`).

A numerically stable way of calculating this in python with numpy arrays might be:

```
import numpy as np
def cumulative_discount(rewards, discount):
    future_cumulative_reward = 0
    assert np.issubdtype(rewards.dtype, np.floating), rewards.dtype
    cumulative_rewards = np.empty_like(rewards)
    for i in range(len(rewards) - 1, -1, -1):
        cumulative_rewards[i] = rewards[i] + discount * future_cumulative_reward
        future_cumulative_reward = cumulative_rewards[i]
    return cumulative_rewards
```

However, this relies on a python loop. Given that this is such a common calculation, surely there's an existing vectorized solution relying on some other standard functions without resorting to cythonization.

Note that any solution using something like `np.power(discount, np.arange(len(rewards))` won't be stable.

Comment: @CrazyIvan Agreed, I was being a bit sloppy, will fix.

Comment: @CrazyIvan oh, that was another mistake, you answered correctly, but I did not ask the question I intended. Sorry about that. (I have revised the question; the for loop is still the same one that should be vectorized).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use [scipy.signal.lfilter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html) to solve the recurrence relation:

```
def alt(rewards, discount):
    """
    C[i] = R[i] + discount * C[i+1]
    signal.lfilter(b, a, x, axis=-1, zi=None)
    a[0]*y[n] = b[0]*x[n] + b[1]*x[n-1] + ... + b[M]*x[n-M]
                          - a[1]*y[n-1] - ... - a[N]*y[n-N]
    """
    r = rewards[::-1]
    a = [1, -discount]
    b = [1]
    y = signal.lfilter(b, a, x=r)
    return y[::-1]
```

---

This script tests that the result is the same:

```
import scipy.signal as signal
import numpy as np

def orig(rewards, discount):
    future_cumulative_reward = 0
    cumulative_rewards = np.empty_like(rewards, dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(len(rewards) - 1, -1, -1):
        cumulative_rewards[i] = rewards[i] + discount * future_cumulative_reward
        future_cumulative_reward = cumulative_rewards[i]
    return cumulative_rewards

def alt(rewards, discount):
    """
    C[i] = R[i] + discount * C[i+1]
    signal.lfilter(b, a, x, axis=-1, zi=None)
    a[0]*y[n] = b[0]*x[n] + b[1]*x[n-1] + ... + b[M]*x[n-M]
                          - a[1]*y[n-1] - ... - a[N]*y[n-N]
    """
    r = rewards[::-1]
    a = [1, -discount]
    b = [1]
    y = signal.lfilter(b, a, x=r)
    return y[::-1]

# test that the result is the same
np.random.seed(2017)

for i in range(100):
    rewards = np.random.random(10000)
    discount = 1.01
    expected = orig(rewards, discount)
    result = alt(rewards, discount)
    if not np.allclose(expected,result):
        print('FAIL: {}({}, {})'.format('alt', rewards, discount))
        break
```

Comment: Woah, that's neat. Does it boil down to the same numerical computations under the hood for this special case?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. The C code that defines `lfilter` can be [found here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.0.0/scipy/signal/lfilter.c.src#L130).

Comment: Indeed, [this function](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.0.0/scipy/signal/lfilter.c.src#L602) confirms it. (BTW, discount is usually < 1 in these contexts)

Comment: FYI a quick `%timeit` check of `orig(np.ones(1000), 0.95)` vs `alt(np.ones(1000), 0.95)` tells me 295 µs ± 6.29 µs per loop (orig) and 11.5 µs ± 28.7 ns per loop (alt), so the approach seems to do well in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1):

The computation you describe is known as [Horner's rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HornersRule.html) or Horner's method of evaluating polynomials. It is implemented in NumPy [polynomial.polyval](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval.html).

However, you want the whole `cumulative_rewards` list, i.e., all the intermediate steps of Horner's rule. NumPy method doesn't return those intermediate values. Your function, decorated with Numba's @jit, could be optimal for that.

As a theoretical possibility, I will point out `polyval` can return the whole list if given a [Hankel matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.hankel.html) of coefficients. This is vectorized but ultimately less efficient than Python loop, because each value of cumulative_reward is computed from scratch, independently of others.

```
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import polyval
from scipy.linalg import hankel

rewards = np.random.uniform(10, 100, size=(100,))
discount = 0.9
print(polyval(discount, hankel(rewards)))
```

This matches the output of

```
print(cumulative_discount(rewards, discount))
```

Comment: Well, like you say `polyval` isn't sufficient here since we're interested in the whole array. I take it since you're suggesting Numba that the answer is negative to my original question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a numpy-only solution, go for this (borrowing structure from unutbu's answer):

```py
def alt2(rewards, discount):
    tmp = np.arange(rewards.size)
    tmp = tmp - tmp[:, np.newaxis]
    w = np.triu(discount ** tmp.clip(min=0)).T
    return (rewards.reshape(-1, 1) * w).sum(axis=0)
```

Proof below.

```py
import numpy as np

def orig(rewards, discount):
    future_cumulative_reward = 0
    cumulative_rewards = np.empty_like(rewards, dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(len(rewards) - 1, -1, -1):
        cumulative_rewards[i] = rewards[i] + discount * future_cumulative_reward
        future_cumulative_reward = cumulative_rewards[i]
    return cumulative_rewards

def alt2(rewards, discount):
    tmp = np.arange(rewards.size)
    tmp = tmp - tmp[:, np.newaxis]
    w = np.triu(discount ** tmp.clip(min=0)).T
    return (rewards.reshape(-1, 1) * w).sum(axis=0)

# test that the result is the same
np.random.seed(2017)

for i in range(100):
    rewards = np.random.random(100)
    discount = 1.01
    expected = orig(rewards, discount)
    result = alt2(rewards, discount)
    if not np.allclose(expected,result):
        print('FAIL: {}({}, {})'.format('alt', rewards, discount))
        break
else:
    print('success')
```

However, this solution does not scale well to big reward arrays, but you can still workaround with stride tricks, [as pointed out here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62820764/11841324).

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to expand unutbu's excellent solution by introducing an initial condition to the cumulative reward. I wanted C[-2] to be approximately equal to C[-1] (steady-state), instead of starting with R[-1]. Here's how to achieve that:

```py
import scipy.signal as signal

def alt(rewards, discount):
    """
    C[i] = R[i] + discount * C[i+1]
    signal.lfilter(b, a, x, axis=-1, zi=None)
    a[0]*y[n] = b[0]*x[n] + b[1]*x[n-1] + ... + b[M]*x[n-M]
                          - a[1]*y[n-1] - ... - a[N]*y[n-N]
    """
    r = rewards[::-1]
    a = [1, -discount]
    b = [1]
    zi = signal.lfilter_zi(b, a) * r[0]  # steady state when input is constant and equal to r[0]
    y = signal.lfilter(b, a, x=r, zi=zi)
    return y[::-1]
```